# I want to send(upload) a file from phone to computer,but it gives an error

Tags: android, sftp, jsch

I want to send a file from phone to computer,but it gives an error(No such File) but i didn't solve this problem.What is the problem?I'm using sftp server.Code :

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
                try {

                    sftpChannel.cd("/sdcard/download");
                     String inputFileName =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"a.txt";

                     sftpChannel.put(inputFileName, "/home/john/desktop");

                } catch (SftpException e) {
                     writeToSDFile("sftp---exception"+e);
                }

                sftpChannel.exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,i solved this problem,Here is the Code:

```
 ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
                writeToSDFile("9");
                try {

                     sftpChannel.cd("/home/john/Desktop");
                        String inputFileName =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/myData.txt";
                        File f = new File(inputFileName);  
                        sftpChannel.put(inputFileName, "/home/john/Desktop/myData.txt");

                } catch (SftpException e) {
                     writeToSDFile("sftp---exception"+e);
                }
```